# A basic question about continuous integration

Tags: jenkins, version-control, jenkins-pipeline, hudson

This is not a programming question, but I don't know any more active forum and besides programmers are the best people to be able to answer my question.

I am trying to understand the rationale behind continuous integration. On one hand, I understand that it is a good practice to daily commit your code before heading to home whether or not the coding and testing is complete or not and then there is continuous integration concept where the minute something is committed, it triggers a build and all the test cases are run. Aren't the two things contradictory?. If we commit daily whatever coding is done, it will cause daily failed builds..Why don't we manually trigger builds once the coding and testing is complete?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you save your code daily is to be sure that your work will not be lost.

On the counterpart the **CI or Continuous Integration is to test if what you produced is ok**, in the majority of projects the CI isn't applied to individual branches ie: `feature`, `bugfix`, it's applied on major branches ie: `master`, `develop`, `releases`, etc. And these branches aren't updated daily as they need a pull request to be update and someone to approval that pull request.

The use case for having CI implemented on individual branches (feature, bugfix) is to check before merging a pull request into a major branch when it will check the tests and if the code builds.

So resuming, yes you need to commit your code daily, but you don't need to apply CI to it daily.

I suggest to you check the Gitflow workflow: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Answer (score 0):

The answer is obvious.

**1. Committing Code:** In general the code is committed only after testing with the environment locally.
Consider `Developer_A` working on `Component_A` hence one has to commit with minimum verification as the scope is to develop Component_A.
No imagine complex system with 50 developer developing `Component_B`...`Component_Z++`
If someone is committing the code without minimum test it is most probably going to give you failed result.

Or else developer might have it committed on development branch that all together depends on SCM strategy adapted in project.

**2. Continues Integration test scope:**
On the other hand integrator principally collects and synergies different codes (Software Components) together into 1 container and perform  different tests.
Most importantly, integrator need to ensure that all the Components Developed from different developers is fitting good and at the end Software is working as expected. To ensure that, Integrator have acceptance criteria and to proactively prevent something which can go wrong, it is important to have these criteria automated with the help of Continues integration.

But among all factors, it is important to give feedback on the quality of software to the  developers. It is best in favor of project (economically), to know about the bug earlier hence Continues Integration and DevOps.
In Complex System it is worth to have automated watcher to catch the sneaked mistakes from developers.

**3 Tools and Automation:**
To create human independent system, automation tools like Jenkins are helpful.
Based on the testing strategy different testing levels can be performed with the help of Automation tools.